# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve Error CS1061'IDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'OpenAsync'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

In ASP.NET Core-6, I am using Dapper with SqlConnection

MAIN CODE:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Dapper;

public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;

    public NIPSenderRepository(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<UserRepository> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private IDbConnection HrmConnection
    {
        get { return new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("HrmConnection")); }
    }

    public async Task UpdateTransactionStatusAsFailed(long payment_id)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IDbConnection _dbConnection = null;
        try
        {      
            _dbConnection = HrmConnection; // Assign the connection here
            if (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                await _dbConnection.OpenAsync();
            }
            string query = "UPDATE pmt_payments SET icount=ISNULL(icount, 0) + 1, processed_dt=GETDATE(), ptystatus='failed' WHERE payment_id = @payment_id";
            await _dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(query, new { payment_id });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("\n Error Update transaction with payment_id: ").Append(payment_id).Append(" \n");
            sb.Append("\n ==================================== \n");
            sb.Append(ex.Message);
            sb.Append("\n ==================================== \n");
            _logger.LogError(sb.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Check if the connection is not null before trying to close it
            if (_dbConnection != null && _dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                _dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Error  CS1061  'IDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'OpenAsync' and no accessible extension method 'OpenAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IDbConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What could be wrong?

Kindly help resolve it with complete code

Comment: Did you mean to use the interface `IDbConnection` or the class `DbConnection`?

Comment: That interface does not have indeed an OpenAsync method [but it has Open()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @gunr2171 - How do you mean. Kindly help resolve the issue

Comment: *”What could be wrong?”* - The error is telling you that this method doesn’t exist on this type.  Can you indicate specifically why you expect otherwise?  Is your IDE showing this method in its intellisense suggestions?  Is there documentation you’re referring to?  Something else?

Comment: There is no ``OpenAsync`` method in ``IDbConnection`` interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection?view=net-7.0#methods

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the code as follows.

The `HrmConnection` property looks useless in my opinion. I put it away. Instead, the `SqlConnection` object is created directly where it is needed.

The connection string is obtained from `IConfiguration` directly in the constructor and stored in the field for future use.
At the same time, the `IConfiguration` is not used anywhere else, so we do not store it.

[using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) will automatically free up resources, even in case of an exception.

```
public class UserRepository
{    
    private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public UserRepository(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<UserRepository> logger)
    { 
        _logger = logger;
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("HrmConnection");
    }

    public async Task UpdateTransactionStatusAsFailed(long payment_id)
    {        
        try
        {
            await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync();            
            string query = "UPDATE pmt_payments SET icount=ISNULL(icount, 0) + 1, processed_dt=GETDATE(), ptystatus='failed' WHERE payment_id = @payment_id";
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, new { payment_id });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder()
                .Append("\n Error Update transaction with payment_id: ")
                .Append(payment_id)
                .Append(" \n")
                .Append("\n ==================================== \n")
                .Append(ex.Message)
                .Append("\n ==================================== \n");

            _logger.LogError(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```